# Calling a function with (rest [1[2]]) in Clojure as an argument is different from calling with argument ([2])

Tags: clojure

So I've been solving a 4clojure problem, where I need to implement the function flatten and I am trying to debug my solution, which is:

```
(defn fn1 [x]

    (if (not (or (list? x) (vector? x)))
        (list x)
        (if (empty? (rest x))

            (if (not (or (list? x) (vector? x)))
                (list x)
                (fn1 (first x))
            )    

            (if (or (list? (first x)) (vector? (first x)))
                ( concat (fn1 (first x)) (fn1 (rest x)) )
                ( concat (fn1 (list (first x))) (fn1 (rest x)) )
            )

        )
    )
)
```

While trying to debug, I encountered the following behaviour:

```
user=> (fn1 (rest [1[2]]))
(([2]))
user=> (rest [1[2]])
([2])
user=> (fn1 '([2]))
(2)
```

What is the reason behind that and how can I get around it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although they render the same at the REPL, `(rest [1 [2]])` and `'([2])` have different types:

```
(type (rest [1 [2]])) ; clojure.lang.PersistentVector$ChunkedSeq

(type '([2]))         ; clojure.lang.PersistentList
```

The former answers `false` to `list?` whereas the latter answers `true`.

Comment: The `list?` function is a trap for the unwary. There is basically no scenario where you should ever call it instead of `seq?` or some other predicate.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't looked to much in your code, but it looks like because

```
> (type (rest [1 2]))
clojure.lang.PersistentVector$ChunkedSeq
> (vector? (rest [1 2]))
false
> (list? (rest [1 2]))
false
> (seq? (rest [1 2]))
true
```

So if `rest` of list is a list, `rest` of vector is not a list or vector,
but `ChunkedSeq`